# Why does Xcode 5.1 still assume true over TRUE?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

When I type TRUE or FALSE while holding down caps it still assumes I want the lowercase true or false. When working with Objective-C I believe we are supposed to use the uppercase version even though they are currently equivalent, but the fact that Xcode keeps changing it to true or false has me second guessing.

Anyone know if we can just use true and false now?

Comment: we should use `YES`/`NO` in ObjC code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`true` and `false` were introduced by C99. `true` is defined to be the integer constant `1` and `false` is defined to be the integer constant `0` per the spec.

Apple's `TRUE` and `FALSE` which predate C99 by quite a distance are defined identically.

So the things are interchangeable.

However, in contrast to your claim, in Objective-C people ordinarily use `YES` and `NO` rather than `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

As of recent versions of Clang that support boxed expressions, those are defined as:

```
#define YES __objc_yes
#define NO  __objc_no
```

For which the compiler substitutes `(BOOL)1` and `(BOOL)0` if used directly as literals. The difference comes when you use boxed expressions. This:

```
@YES
```

... is an `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`. Amongst other things, it'll compare by identity (rather than by value) to every other bool `YES` object. This:

```
@(true)
```

... is an `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]`. It'll compare by value but not by identity.